# <init>(Ljava/util/Properties;[Ljava/lang/String;)V while running Cucumber script in eclipse

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

[My code and packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaI3z.png)

Console:

```
TestRunner
runner.TestRunner
initializationError(runner.TestRunner)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(Ljava/util/Properties;[Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

Comment: This is not a question!

Comment: You are a new user, please have a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

You get this kind of error when two libraries are not compatible.

I think in your case the cucumber version is not compatible with your eclipse runner. Check the versions compatibility or simply try to upgrade the cucumber / eclipse runner to most recent versions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply